# Numpy Namespace Issue

Tags: python, numpy

I currently have the following function:

```
def add_bch(compressed):
    k = 16 #input blocks of 16 bits.

    prim_poly = Poly([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]) # x^5+x^2+1
    prim_poly_3 = Poly([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]) #prim_poly^3 -> x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+1
    prim_poly_5 = Poly([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]) #prim_poly^5 -> x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1

    gen_poly = npp.polymul(npp.polymul(prim_poly, prim_poly_3), prim_poly_5)[0]

    compressed = add_padding(compressed, k)

    compressed_with_ecc = []
    for i in range(len(compressed)/k):
        block = compressed[(k*i):(k*(i+1))]
        block_poly = bitstr_to_poly(block)
        quotient, remainder = npp.polydiv(block_poly, gen_poly)
        compressed_with_ecc.append(poly_to_bitstr(block. remainder))

    return Bits().join(compressed_with_ecc)
```

Where the relevant import statements are:

```
from bitstring import BitArray, Bits
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as npp
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as Poly
```

When I run the code, I get the error:

```
bash-4.2$ python send_mess < pg2600.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_mess", line 113, in <module>
    encoded = add_bch(compressed)
  File "send_mess", line 105, in add_bch
    quotient, remainder = npp.polydiv(block_poly, gen_poly)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.py", line 408, in polydiv
    return c1/c2[-1], c1[:1]*0
  File "<string>", line 373, in __rtruediv__
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'quo' referenced before assignment
```

I know that numpy imports can cause namespace issues, but try as I might I can't figure out what the problem is here. The one thing that occurred to me was the two numpy import statements might clash, but it seems to me like they should be separate from each other, as it should be:

```
numpy
  ...
  polynomial
     ...
     Polynomial
     polynomial
        ...
        polymul
        polydiv
        ...
     ...
  ...
```

However I did try:

```
from bitstring import BitArray, Bits
import numpy.polynomial as npp
```

With all the relevant name changes, to no avail. I also tried directly importing the everything, so:

```
from bitstring import BitArray, Bits
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polymul, polydiv
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as Poly
```

Which also did not work. At no point in the function (or my program in general) do I refer to a variable "quo", and I don't see where any of my code could have stepped on numpy's toes.

Comment: Maybe a bug inside `Polynomial.__rtruediv__`?

Comment: Which type `block` and `block_poly`? Maybe this input whose `polydiv` has a problem.

Comment: block is an BitArray, from the python-bitstring library. block_poly is  a numpy polynomial.

Comment: I decided to use a different approach to my program for other reasons as it is, so the question is somewhat moot from my perspective, although it might be nice to get an answer for future searchers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in numpy.  In the implementation of `__rtruediv__` at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/polynomial/_polybase.py#L421, you can see that if `len(self.coef)` is not 1, the statement

```
    return self.__class__(quo, self.domain, self.window)
```

is executed, but `quo` is not defined.

Here's a simple example that generates the error:

```
In [1]: import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as npp

In [2]: p1 = npp.Polynomial([1,2])

In [3]: p2 = npp.Polynomial([3,4])

In [4]: npp.polydiv(p1, p2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-00c25f56fb20> in <module>()
----> 1 npp.polydiv(p1, p2)

    /Users/warren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.pyc in polydiv(c1, c2)
    406     len2 = len(c2)
    407     if len2 == 1 :
--> 408         return c1/c2[-1], c1[:1]*0
    409     elif len1 < len2 :
    410         return c1[:1]*0, c1

/Users/warren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.pyc in __rtruediv__(self, other)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'quo' referenced before assignment
```

I reported the issue here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4631.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note here. You should not be calling `polydiv`, but rather doing `divmod(block_poly, gen_poly)` using the Python `divmod` operator. The error for the code as given is indeed in `__rtruediv__`, but it is rather an accident.  The function call treats the division as two degree 0 polynomials with polynomial coefficients and, because the `polynomial.py` file has `from __future__ import division` up top, tries to do a true divide. A more direct way to get the error is
`operator.truediv(block_poly, gen_poly)`.